# Getting a TypeError: state.posts is not iterable after what it seems was a successful POST request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My current project allows a user to enter some title and description, and dispatches an appropriate action. It seems to work fine as it displays CREATE_POST_REQUEST, followed by CREATE_POST_SUCCESS with the newly created post object returned from the API call. However, also attached is an error which says "TypeError: state.posts is not iterable". I have an initial state which is an object that has the posts field set to an empty array initially. Here are some code snippets.

postsReducer.js

```
import {
    FETCH_POSTS_REQUEST,
    FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE,
    CREATE_POST_REQUEST,
    CREATE_POST_SUCCESS,
    CREATE_POST_FAILURE
} from "./postsConstants";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    loading: false,
    posts: [],
    error: '',
};

export const postsReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_POSTS_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
            }
        case FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                posts: action.payload,
                error: '',
            }
        case FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.payload,
            }
        case CREATE_POST_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
            }
        case CREATE_POST_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: '',
                posts: [...state.posts, action.payload],
            }
        case CREATE_POST_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.payload,
            }
        default: return state;
    }
};
```

postsActions.js

```
import {
    FETCH_POSTS_REQUEST,
    FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE,
    CREATE_POST_REQUEST,
    CREATE_POST_SUCCESS,
    CREATE_POST_FAILURE
} from "./postsConstants";
import * as api from '../../api/posts';

export const fetchPosts = () => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_POSTS_REQUEST
            });
            const { data } = await api.fetchPosts();
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS,
                payload: data
            });
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE,
                payload: error.message
            });
        }
    }
};

export const createPost = (post) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            dispatch({
                type: CREATE_POST_REQUEST
            });
            const { data } = await api.createPost(post);
            dispatch({
                type: CREATE_POST_SUCCESS,
                payload: data
            });
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch({
                type: CREATE_POST_FAILURE,
                payload: error.message
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Compose.js (user enters title and post descriptions)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Typography, Button, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { createPost } from "../../redux/index";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

import useStyles from './styles';

// validation schema
const validationSchema = yup.object({
    title: yup
        .string('Enter a title.')
        .required('A title is required.'),
    description: yup
        .string('Enter a post description.')
        .required('Post description is required.'),
});

function Compose() {;
    const classes = useStyles();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const history = useHistory();

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            title: '',
            description: ''
        },
        validationSchema: validationSchema,
        onSubmit: (values) => {
            dispatch(createPost(values));
        }
    });

    return (
        <Container className={classes.container} maxWidth="lg" >
            <form className={classes.form} autoComplete="off" onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                <Typography
                    className={classes.header}
                    variant="h3"
                >
                    Compose
                </Typography>
                <Typography
                    className={classes.postLabel}
                    variant="h6"
                >
                    Title
                </Typography>
                <TextField 
                    className={classes.postTitle}
                    name="title"
                    variant="outlined"
                    label="Enter Post Title"
                    fullWidth
                    value={formik.values.title}
                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                    error={formik.touched.title && !!(formik.errors.title)}
                    helperText={formik.touched.title && formik.errors.title}
                />
                <Typography
                    variant="h6"
                    className={classes.postLabel}
                >
                    Post
                </Typography>
                <TextField 
                    className={classes.postDescription}
                    name="description"
                    variant="outlined"
                    label="Enter Post Description"
                    fullWidth
                    multiline
                    rows={20}
                    value={formik.values.description}
                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                    error={formik.touched.description && !!(formik.errors.description)}
                    helperText={formik.touched.description && formik.errors.description}
                />
                <Button
                    className={classes.buttonSubmit}
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    type="submit"
                    size="large"
                    fullWidth                    
                >
                    Publish
                </Button>
            </form>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Compose;
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Edit: Forgot to add some logs to show.
[logs when creating a new post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpneb.png)

Edit #2: Added a console.log to display the state.posts.posts property after the createPost() call. It seems to be an empty array...

[console.log results after createPost()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CbCS.png)

Comment: Does it display correnctly when you `console.log` your state?

Comment: Hi, just added the logs in the original post, sorry about that.

Comment: Just added a console.log of my state.posts.posts after the dispatch call in Compose.js, it seems that it is an empty array. Added an image in the description @SamTheFam

Comment: In your posts action add console log on `data` which you got from api.fetchposts() .

Comment: Redux dev tools is one of the best . Please install it . You can easily debug your state and actions dispatched along with your payload info.

Comment: Thank you @Shyam I have installed it and updated the post. Also I added console log on data on both api.fetchPosts() and api.getPosts() and seem to return the correct posts.

Comment: Okay so when you are fetching the posts what is the value you get in data is it an object or array ?.

Comment: It is returning an object containing a field called posts which stores an array of posts.

Comment: @Shyam Thank you for your help, I changed the payload to data.posts to ensure it holds the array portion of the returned object.

Comment: Accept and upvote the answers which adds value to you . Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data from the fetch posts api returns an object with the key posts . You need to change your dispatch as

```
dispatch({
                type: FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS,
                payload: data.posts
            });
```

You were getting the error earlier because you were trying to do [...state.posts] where your posts was object instead of an array .

Answer (score 0):

This problem is mostly caused by immutable object. In the infrastructure you are using, you should check whether the states are immutable or mutable. I recommend that you review the links I left below.

https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/

https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data

Comment: Thank you for the links, I will have a look.